# Utility applications in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am quite new to DDD and have come across a scenario that i'm not to sure how to handle.

I have an application that is used to track vehicles.  This application is what will be implementing the "core" of the domain for the business i am working for.  Not only is this application going to be used, there will be other utility programs that must be created and used in order to help this "core/main" application function.

for example:
there is an windows service needed that will perform configured queries on a database and return results to an external database that my routing application will use.  This windows service has the concept of a **QuerySettings** class that can be created and is then executed by this application.

Question1:
What do you call **utility** applications like the above described in DDD? ( it definitely isn't the main core of the domain but it's needed in order for the core application to work )

QUestion2:
Is **QuerySettings** a domain model? if not what is it and where should it be placed within following the onion architecture?

Answer (score 0):

For question1: You may have a look at Bounded context, I think Bounded context contains a group of Domain models that represent concepts in a subdomain(or a core domain). You may need to map or share domain models in different bounded contexts to handle your business, this depends on your bounded context strategy, share-kernal, anti-corruption-layer(to name a few).

For question2: I have little information of how **QuerySettings** works but in general it is a domain model but in a generic subdomain, not in your vehicle tracking core domain. In core domain's view, it maybe an infrastructure concept.